# webservice DateTime unexpected value?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

When I use the system.datetime as my datamember it returns a strange format in my datagridview.

My Datamembers looks like this:

```
    [DataMember(Name = "TimeAdded")]
    public DateTime TimeAdded;
```

And my AddStudent looks like this:

```
    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        student.StudentID = (++eCount).ToString();
        student.TimeAdded = DateTime.Now; // not important more so the method to get the correct format
        students.Add(student);
    }
```

The output I get is `2012-04-12T03:10:42.8138255+01:00` is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the fact that your dates are set to `default(DateTime)`, then you want yamen's answer, if you don't like the format the `DateTime` is showing, then add another property onto Student that uses a [standard DateTime format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) like so.

```
public class Student
{
   // existing date, don't expose this
   public DateTime TimeAdded;

   // expose this instead
   [DataMember(Name = "TimeAddedString")]
   public string TimeAddedString 
   {
      //show as "Monday, January 01, 0001 12:00 AM"
      get { return this.TimeAdded.ToString("f"); }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey Steve still getting a horrible format with this. This is what I am getting `2012-04-12T03:01:50.9184029+01:00`

Comment: I think Steve's answer is the right one if the format is the issue. Have you changed your DataGridView to look at the property TimeAddedString rather than just TimeAdded?

Comment: Actually no its just set to .Value when its sent to the client.

Comment: @KirstyWhite: I think this is the answer that you want. Just add the DataMember attribute to the above property named appropriately (maybe TimeAddedString) and perhaps remove the DataMember on the original TimeAdded.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
student.TimeAdded = DateTime.Now;
```

Right now you're just converting a null time to local time.

Comment: `2012-04-12T03:05:34.2671777+01:00` This is what I get if I try your method Yamen. All I want is the time (normal format and date normal format)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Student
{
   public string TimeAddedString
   {
      get 
      { 
          return this.TimeAdded.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"); 
          // your desired format can goes here
      } 
   }
}
public void AddStudent(Student student)
{
    student.StudentID = (++eCount).ToString();
    student.TimeAdded = DateTime.Now; // or your desired datetime
    students.Add(student);
}
```

Comment: This gives the very same result as the original question since DateTime() initialises to `0001-01-01T00:00:00`

Comment: It's still likely you want DateTime.Now not DateTime.Today considering Today initialises to midnight and the property is called 'TimeAdded'.

Comment: All methods so far still give a horrible format, Ive tryed everything and its still coming out wonky.

Comment: Still no difference the output looks like this: 2012-04-12T03:05:34.2671777+01:00

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting incoming student time added you need to re-assign it:

```
public void AddStudent(Student student)
{
        student.StudentID = (++eCount).ToString();
        student.TimeAdded = student.TimeAdded.ToLocalTime();
        students.Add(student);
}
```